# Quartz.NET как выполнить один триггер несколько раз одновременно

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz

Нужно запускать триггер Job и код это успешно делает. Но мне нужно будет еще один запустить и в этот момент всё упадет. Проще говоря, нужно запустить триггер вот так:

```
Jobs.TaskScheduler.Start(mclass);
Jobs.TaskScheduler.Start(mclass);
Jobs.TaskScheduler.Start(mclass);
```

Сами классы выглядят вот так:

```
public class TaskScheduler 
{
    public static async void Start(MyClass mclass)
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        await scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<TaskJob>().Build();

        TriggerKey zTriggerKey = new TriggerKey("trigger1", "group1");
        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity(zTriggerKey)
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
                .RepeatForever())
            .Build();
        job.JobDataMap.Put("mclass", mclass);
        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}


public class TaskJob : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var dataMap = context.MergedJobDataMap;
        var task = (MyClass)dataMap["mclass"];
        Console.WriteLine(mclass.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось проще чем я ожидал. Зря вопрос делал, но может кому-нибудь пригодится.
Для решения нужно в TriggerKey менять идентификатор. Чтобы не пересекались друг с другом. Мне помогло это.

```
public static async void Start(MyClass mclass)
{
    IScheduler scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
    await scheduler.Start();

    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<TaskJob>().Build();

    TriggerKey zTriggerKey = new TriggerKey(mclass.Name, "group1");
    var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity(zTriggerKey)
        .StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
            .WithIntervalInMinutes(1)
            .RepeatForever())
        .Build();
    job.JobDataMap.Put("mclass", mclass);
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```